# Как запустить эмулятор Android из терминала на Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu

Интересует именно настройка и запуск из командной строки: AVD Manager подходит не всегда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перейти в папку <android-sdk>/tools.

Получить список системных образов исполнения.

```
./android list targets
```

Создать виртуальное устройство, передав параметром t номер нужного образа.

```
./android create avd -n sample -t 1 -c 128M -f
```

Запустить виртуально устройство.

```
./emulator -avd sample
```